# using geth attach local node and call rpc api. why the output omitted some complex content?

Tags: go-ethereum, console

I implemented a custom RPC api, it will return nested structs, but I called it in geth console, I found there's a "..." displayed (some content is omitted), I want to know how to print the full response content?

I used curl to call this api, the response is full.

Comment: Please give more details and maybe join a screenshot or a paste of the return you are talking about.